# Get the name of an ADO data type from the recordset.field.type property?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to produce a list of the fields (name, type and size)  from an Access table.  This simple VB code gives me **almost** what I need:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myTable")
For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Print #1, rs.Fields(x).Name & vbTab & rs.Fields(x).Type & vbTab & rs.Fields(x).Size
Next
```

However the "Type" of course is a numeric constant like "10" instead of something like "Varchar".

I was going to do this:

```
Select Case rs.Fields(x).Type
  Case adChar
    fieldType = "adChar"
  Case adInteger
    fieldType = "adInteger"
  Case adDouble
ETCETERA....
```

But I wonder if there's a better way, something like DataTypeEnum.FindName(Type) or something?

Apologies in advance if this is a "stupid question", but I don't work in VB every day and Googling has produced no clear answer on this.

Comment: it's not a stupid question. Try `Debug.Print TypeName(rs.Fields(x)), VarType(rs.Fields(x))` i havent tested it but just give it a go

Comment: There's no easy way to convert (in VBA) an enum value into its equivalent "name".  The way you have it is pretty much how you do it.

Comment: Allen Browne has a good [page listing the constants](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html) and he's even got a [FieldTypeName](http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html) (scroll down a bit on that page) function, but you'll probably still have to roll your own to get exactly what you want.

Comment: @mehow - Thank you for the quick response, with a little fiddling what I wound up with was TypeName(rs.Fields(x).Value), which gave me 90% of what I needed (it reported two "Currency" fields as "Null" but I can live with that.)   Thanks again.

Comment: @user1071914 - it will report 'Null' if the value is null. The way you are doing it, you aren't inspecting the field/column ADO type, but the VBA type of a value in the field/column. Admittedly, the differences here are a bit academic in a pure Access context though (the mapping between the ADO and VBA type systems is pretty direct, and Access as a database engine doesn't use dynamic typing like SQLite).

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - yes, I tried TypeName(rs.Fields(x)) first.  Unfortunately it did exactly what I told it to do and reported that the type of the field was "Field" - accurate, but not useful.   I solved the immediate problem as inticated above, but it would be nice to find an elegant "general" solution for this.

Comment: @user1071914 - urgh, sorry, should have checked before I made the comment! TypeName(rs.Fields(x)) will return "Field" because VBA is picking up the object, Fields being a collection of Field objects; TypeName(rs.Fields(x).Value) will get the type name of the value. (Value is the default property of a Field object, so usually doesn't have to be explicitly referred to.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers in the comments under the question (above) are excellent, unfortunately they boil down to "you can't get there from here."   There is no simple way to get the data type **contained** in a Field.   The closest I was able to come was to do this for the quick-n-dirty:

```
Function Scripting()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ff As String
    Dim fieldType As String
    ff = "c:\Users\me\Desktop\Structure.txt"
    Open ff For Output As #1
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myTable")
    For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Print #1, rs.Fields(x).Name & vbTab & TypeName(rs.Fields(x).Value) & vbTab & rs.Fields(x).Size
    Next
    Close #1
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

You would be well advised go to [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html)'s excellent page and grab his  FieldTypeName() function for a better solution.

Thanks to everyone (mehow, blackhawk, Chris Rolliston and Tim Williams) that chipped in on the answer.