# Determining a DAO Access Table Field's Format to apply to an Excel Worksheet

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am using the CopyFromRecordset command within Access to copy a series of tables into Excel. No worries with this process. My problem is making this routine be able to determine what format should be assigned to each sheet column of the workbook. I have extracted the Table's Field Object Type values and have compared these to the reference Microsoft Reference for the Field.Type property. ( [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526865(v=EXCHG.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526865%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx) ). Unfortunately, what is returned does not accurately reflect the definitions in Access when compared to the MS stated values.

1) A date field returns a Type value of 8 corresponding to a vbString

2) A currency field returns a Type value of 5 corresponding to a vbDouble

3) A text field returns a Type value of 10 that is not even listed

4) A formated vbDouble returns a Type value of 7 coorisponding to a vbDate

The only return value that does seem to provide a valid reference if for an Integer Field with a Type value of 3

How do I get a valid table field format reference so that I can then format the corresponding worksheet columns correctly? I really don't want to have to create a reference table that will provide the desired format for each field in every table to be extracted. Fine as a work-around but certainly not very flexible as the table structure being extracted is dynamic via a series of CrossTab queries and not something I can easily use an Excel Template as I read as one solution.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: That list of values in your link is for Exchange Server....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735653/get-the-name-of-an-ado-data-type-from-the-recordset-field-type-property

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the links and clarification to where I was headed off in the wrong direction with my efforts. The referenced link above by Ted led me to [Allen Brown's](http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html) function for returning the formating for the fields of a Table. As a result, I was able to accomplish my goal. Here is the specific code as reference.

```
    'Write the Table Field Names to the Named Worksheet as Column Headers
    'and format the columns for the Table.Field format

        intRowCount = rst3.RecordCount
        intColumnCount = rst3.Fields.Count
        For i = 0 To intColumnCount - 1
            xlSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst3.Fields(i).Name

            If i = 0 Then
                .Sheets(strTable).Columns(i + 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End If

            If i < 3 Then
                .Sheets(strTable).Columns(i + 1).EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End If

            intFormat = CLng(rst3.Fields(i).Type)
            .Sheets(strTable).Columns(i + 1).EntireColumn.Select
            Select Case intFormat
                Case 3
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "00"
                Case 5
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                Case 7
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                Case 8
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                Case 10
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            End Select

        Next i      'Next Column - Table Field to be copied
```

It may not be the most efficient as I am still developing ways to best use Excel objects from within Access.

If anyone has code improvements, I am certainly open to suggestions.  Thanks again all.